# JavaScript - change only one button by click with id and addEventListener

Tags: javascript

When I press the first button it changes but when I press the second button nothing happens.
How can you do this so that even if there are more buttons he will listen to the click of a button?

I want when I press one button only it will change

My HTML and JavaScript:

```
<button id="mybtn1"> Click </button>
<button id="mybtn1"> Click </button>
<script>


document.getElementById('mybtn1').addEventListener('click', 
  function() {
    this.textContent = 'Hello there!';
  }
);
```

thank's

Comment: using id is not a right way to listen event on multiple items, use class instead

Comment: Duplicate IDs are invalid. Use classes, class selectors, and an [`Array` iteration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Methods) method, or event delegation instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`id` should be unique in a document. Use `class` instead. Then use [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to go through all the buttons and attach the event individually:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.mybtn1').forEach(function(btn){
  btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.textContent = 'Hello there!';
  });
});
```

```html
<button class="mybtn1"> Click </button>
<button class="mybtn1"> Click </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```js
let buttons = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("button"));


buttons.map((b) =>{
  b.addEventListener('click', 
() => {
buttons.map((c) => c.textContent = 'click')
b.textContent = 'Hello there!';
});
})
```

```html
<button id="mybtn1"> Click </button>
<button id="mybtn1"> Click </button>
```

I hope it helps.